# Change Explorer character encoding using JavaScript or HTML

Tags: html, encoding, explorer

I'm using the UTF-8 charset to write my HTML and some of the text is in Hebrew.

I use the next lines to specify language for browsers:

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="he">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Some Explorer browsers which are set on **Encoding: Auto-Select** recognize my website as Hebrew and view the pages in the Hebrew (Windows) encoding. This makes the text show as gibberish because it is in UTF-8.

How can I use HTML or JavaScript to force all browsers to use the UTF-8 encoding and ignore any local settings that say otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the browser setting of character encoding, if auto-selection is *disabled*. In such conditions, browsers give the user the final word; this is reflected in the HTML5 draft, which describes, in [Determining the character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding), the first step thusly: “If the user has explicitly instructed the user agent to override the document's character encoding with a specific encoding, optionally return that encoding with the confidence certain and abort these steps.”

The setting Encoding: Auto-Select *enables* auto-selection, and in your case, this makes browsers apply UTF-8, unless HTTP headers say otherwise. With the given data, it is impossible to say what goes wrong, if you really experience the problem when Auto-Select is *on*.